# match.arg(alternative) error appearing while trying to carry out t-test - R

Tags: r, t-test

Hello everyone :) I'm quite new to R so having quite a few difficulties atm but after trying to do a t-test I'm getting this error:

```
Error in match.arg(alternative) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

This is the code I've used:

```
data %>%
  t.test(mean_resp_rew, condition, data = data)
data
```

and I'm very unsure as to what is going wrong.

Edit (not sure if this is the right way of giving reproducible data haha) the df is called data:

data sample:
[image: df sample]

data_summary:
[image: data_summary]

Comment: Please use a small reproducible example.  I guess you need `data = .`

Comment: If you need additional help, please add sample data to your question. Just a small example to illustrate the problem. `dput()` is a nice command for generating a copy/pasteable example of an R object, e.g., `dput(df[1:10, c("relevant", "columns")])` for the first 10 rows of the relevant columns of `df`.

Comment: Yeah, pictures of data are not nice to work with. That's why we ask for `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable. `t.test` expects raw data, not already-computed means and variances. And it expects two samples. You seem to have 4 categories?

Comment: Here's [the FAQ on creating reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). Seeing your data it looks like the relevant columns are `condition` and `response`, so `dput(df[1:10, c("condition", "response")])` should work for the first 10 rows. But you should also refine what you want - a t.test is a test of 2 means, not 4. Maybe a linear model or an anova would be appropriate - but what sort of test to do is a question for stats.stackexchange, not stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe `x %>% foo(y)` is interpreted as `foo(x, y)`. So your code is interpreted as `t.test(data, mean_resp_rew, condition, data = data)`, with the `data` argument first and last. Looking at the `?t.test` help page, if you use a data argument it expects a `formula`, so we could try this:

```
df %>% t.test(mean_resp_rew ~ condition, data = .)
```

Which should work assuming `mean_resp_rew` and `condition` are columns in your `df` data frame (and that `condition` has 2 unique values). There's no nesting, so we don't gain anything from the pipe in this case, so I would recommend keeping it simple with

```
t.test(mean_resp_rew ~ condition, data = df)
```

Comment: hiya! thank you so much for your response :)
I'm not sure if I'll be able to explain this correctly but mean_resp_rew is a product of a calculation earlier in the code and is stored under data_summary, so whenever i try to use it in the t-test it's telling me mean_resp_rew isn't found (which is why I initially put the pipeline as it was the only thing that worked) I've tried doing data = summary data which also doesn't work so I'm a bit stuck :(

Comment: You need to have access to both `mean_resp_rew` and `condition`. And they need to be the same length. If they are in different data frames you could do `t.test(data_summary$mean_resp_rew, df$condition)`, but in that case `data_summary` and `df` must have the same number of rows. If you need more help, please add sample data to your question to make it reproducible.

Comment: uhmm i added screenshots of the sample although I'm not sure if thats helpful or not :( the two are unfortunately not the right lengths - tried various combinations of ```data_summary$mean_resp_rew ~ data_summary$condition, data = data``` but no success

Comment: Yeah, pictures of data are not nice to work with. That's why we ask for `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable. `t.test` expects raw data, not already-computed means and variances. And it expects two samples. You seem to 4 categories?

Comment: hiya! thank you so much for your help and time earlier - turns out we were all over complicating it and were supposed to use the original ```resp_per_rew``` variable instead of the mean one which heavily complicated things, all sorted now :)